# "Area code is not set" when trying to send emails

Tags: magento2, email, magento2.4.4, area

I am trying to send emails programmatically on Magento 2.4.4-p5 using the TransportBuilder, but I get an exception: *Area code is not set*, even if I set it under the *setTemplateOptions* method.

This is the content of my custom method used to send emails that is added in a helper file.

```
        $sender = ['email' => 'custom@domain.com', 'name' => 'Domain'];
        $vars = [
            'message' => 'test here'
        ];
        $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('test_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => 0])
            ->setTemplateVars($vars)
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($toEmail);

        $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
```

A workaround would be to set the area as *GLOBAL*, but then the email template is not to be found.

Is this a known issue?
Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Include this into your code is like this.

```
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
```

...........
...........

```
$storeScope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
$transport = $this->transportBuilder
           ->setTemplateIdentifier('test_template')
           ->setTemplateOptions([
               'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
               'store' => YOUR_CURRENT_STORE_ID,
            ])
           ->setTemplateVars($vars)
           ->setFrom($sender)
           ->addTo($toEmail);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working. Same exception. My example contains static data for area, store, etc., but I also tried with dynamic data as you suggested which is not working.

Comment: confirm this call from frontend of magento, and also store data is pass properly.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that. Also, the email template is associated with the frontend area. I see you're mentioning @storeScope, but you never use it.

Comment: storeScope need to use get current store information like id.

Comment: I noticed the error is caused by the following line: $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport(); Before that line, the area code is defined, but after it, is not defined anymore.

Answer (score 0):

we can use it as `'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND`

the below code had worked for me,hope it helps

```
$storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $templateOptions = [
            'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
            'store' => $storeId
        ];
        $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId, $storeScope)
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->addTo($toEmail)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. I noticed the error is caused by the following line: $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport(); Before that line, the area code is defined, but after it, is not defined anymore. So, I think the error is related to something else, not the email sending code.